# How to see that the Wick product has $0$ expectation.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-analysis, gaussian

In the book "Gaussian Hilbert Spaces" (Svante Janson) the author introduces the Wick product of a finite sequence of $n$ random variables living in a Gaussian Hilbert space $G$ as the orthonormal projection of their product in the $n$-th Wiener chaos, namely:

$$:\xi_1\cdots \xi_n:=\pi_n(\xi_1\cdots\xi_n)$$ 
where the mapping $\pi_n$ is the orthogonal projection of $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)\supset G$ into the $n$-th Wiener chaos.

From this definition (it may be trivial actually) but I don't see how to conclude that the $E(:\xi_1\cdots \xi_n:)=0$, other authors use a different approach defining the Wick product recursively for instance [here.](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Wick_product)

Could you please shed some light on this matter?

Thanks in advance!

(I would prefer some explanation that avoids using multiple Ito-Wiener integrals)

Comment: This is a special case of Theorem 3.8 in that book which says that $\mathbb{E}[:\xi_1 \dots \xi_n : \xi_{n+1} \dots \xi_{n+m}]$ is given by the sum of values of complete Feynman diagrams on $\xi_1, \dots, \xi_{n+m}$ such that no edge joins $\xi_i, \xi_j$ if $i, j \leq n$. In the case $m = 0$, there are no such Feynman diagrams so the sum is empty and the statement is precisely that the expectation you consider is $0$.

Comment: Ohh I see, regarding the theorem $3.8$ the only way to obtain something different from zero is having $m=n$ right? Otherwise I cannot find a complete Feynman diagram like that. @RhysSteele

Comment: That's not quite right. E.g. if there is a complete Feynman diagram on $\xi_1, \dots, \xi_{n+m}$ with those properties then for every $j \geq 1$ there is a complete Feynman diagram on $\xi_1, \dots, \xi_{n+m+2j}$ with those properties which you get by extending the original complete Feynman diagram by an arbitrary pairing of the remaining even number of nodes.

Comment: I've just realised that my comment is far too complicated of a way to see this (I wasn't familiar with the order in which things are set-up in that book so I just flicked through and that was the first thing I found that worked). $: \xi_1 \dots \xi_n : \in H^{:n:} \perp H^{:0:} = \mathbb{R}$. In particular, $\mathbb{E}[: \xi_1 \dots \xi_n : ] = \langle : \xi_1 \dots \xi_n :, 1 \rangle_{L^2} = 0$. In general, for $n \geq 1$ this shows that $H^{:n:}$ consists of centered random variables.

Comment: @RhysSteele thanks man! Indeed this is  a much easier  way to see it. As a side question, do you find this approach (using Feynman diagrams)  useful? I've read other texts online where the Wick product is introduced in a very different way, using the tempered distribution space, etc. On your experience which one is better?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the other constructions are just special cases of this one. This isn't really an approach via Feynman diagrams.Those diagrams are just a convenient graphical notation for what are otherwise awkward formulas. In principle, you can remove the diagrams entirely in the same way that Wick's theorem has a more concise statement using Feynman diagrams but can be stated without then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, the easiest way to see this is to notice that
$$\pi_n(\xi_1 \dots \xi_n) \in H^{:n:} \perp H^{:0:} = \mathbb{R}$$ so that $$\mathbb{E}[\mathpunct{:} \xi_1 \dots \xi_n \mathpunct{:}] = \langle \mathpunct{:} \xi_1 \dots \xi_n \mathpunct{:}, 1 \rangle_{L^2} = 0.$$